# Error in Broadleaf session

Tags: hibernate, broadleaf-commerce

It would be very helpful if anyone could tell why I get this in my application:

> Exceeded max retries to acquire lock on this order

Please note that the app allows user impersonation, and this happens mostly for an order made by an impersonated user. When this happens, there is nothing that we could do on that order.

Broadleaf framework is being is used, from where the error is thrown

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here for someone to be able to help you. If you are using Java, you may wish to retag the question too.

Comment: Question seems to be abandoned, voting to close as too broad.

Comment: This is regarding the broadleaf framework.

Comment: @halfer not too broad, specifically occurs within the broadleaf-commerce-tagged framework.

Answer (score 0):

This order locking mechanism is done so that 2 users (in your case, someone impersonating or the user themselves) cannot modify the same order within the same request. It is also important to note that the order locking mechanisms only occur with POST requests.

Is the customer impersonation feature something that you built yourself or are you using the out-of-the-box Broadleaf impersonation features?

Comment: We have built a custom impersonation feature, not sure about the broadleaf impersonation feature. Can you please share something about it though?

Comment: The customer impersonation features are available in our enterprise edition. You can see a demo of them working. at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6Jec1qVEqg.

Comment: If you are trying to build the impersonation features yourself, you have to lock and unlock the cart manually. You can see in the demo us doing that through the UI on the impersonation frontend that the CSR can control.